# ARRAYFORMULA() so that it works in the whole column except in the last cell of the column - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet. There are currently only 10 rows, the rest were removed.

In cell U6 I am placing a formula with arrayformula() so that it will also extract the values ​​in the cells below.

The problem is that I don't want it to fill to the last cell (of that column) of the sheet, but only to the penultimate cell (of that column).

This would be easy to achieve by changing the range from U6:U to U6:U9.

But the problem would have that every time a new row is introduced below, this new line would not enter within the range.

Try to solve this problem using google apps script with getLastRow() but it doesn't work, it keeps getting the whole column. And with getMaxRow() add thousands of rows to the sheet. Total chaos.

Is there an option to modify the formula of array formula () so that it applies to the entire column except the last cell?

This is my formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl="&"Ref."&"%20"&ENCODEURL(C6:C13)&"%0A"&ENCODEURL(D6:D13)&"%0A"&"Estado:"&"%20"&ENCODEURL(H6:H13)&"%0A"&"Stock:"&"%20"&ENCODEURL(I6:I13)&"%20"&"unidades"&"%0A"&"Precio:"&"%20"&ENCODEURL(P6:P13)))
```

And this is my google apps script with which I tried to subtract the last cell within the range with the getLastRow()-1 but that didn't work:

```
// Generar codigos QR para cada producto en la hoja "Productos".
function generarQR3(){

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName('Productos');

  var row = hoja.getLastRow()-1;

  var referencia = hoja.getRange(6,3,row,1).getA1Notation();
  var nombreProducto = hoja.getRange(6,4,row,1).getA1Notation();
  var estado = hoja.getRange(6,8,row,1).getA1Notation();
  var stock = hoja.getRange(6,9,row,1,).getA1Notation();
  var precio = hoja.getRange(6,16,row,1).getA1Notation();

  var urlAPI = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?';
  var tamanoQR = '200x200';

  var espacio = '"%20"';
  var saltoLinea = '"%0A"';
  var refTexto = '"Ref."';
  var estadoTexto = '"Estado:"';
  var stockTexto = '"Stock:"';
  var unidades = '"unidades"';
  var precioTexto = '"Precio:"';
  var y = '&';
  
  var url = urlAPI + 'chs=' + tamanoQR + '&cht=qr&chl="';

  var qr = '=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(\"' + url + y + refTexto + y + espacio + y + 'ENCODEURL(' + referencia + ')' + y + saltoLinea + y + 'ENCODEURL(' + nombreProducto + ')' + y + saltoLinea + y + estadoTexto + y + espacio + y + 'ENCODEURL(' + estado + ')' + y + saltoLinea + y + stockTexto + y + espacio + y + 'ENCODEURL(' + stock + ')' + y + espacio + y + unidades + y + saltoLinea + y + precioTexto + y + espacio + y + 'ENCODEURL(' + precio + ')' + '))';


  var rangoProductos = hoja.getRange(6,21,1,1);
  rangoProductos.setFormula(qr);

}
```

[image: arrayformula()]

Comment: Make it work is not a question.  And `that didn't work` is not an explanation.

Comment: Personally I avoid the use of Array Formula with scripts because it messes up the last row calculation.  But generally speaking I don't like the use of formulas at all.

Comment: I think that in my text I have explained my current situation, as well as the behavior of the formula and what I want. I have also explained the behavior that I get from getLastRow() and getMaxRows() when I apply the formula to the cell directly via app script. As well as I have also asked my question. I don't see where it is in the problem and why you say it is not an explanation. @Cooper

Comment: Generally I try to avoid the use of formulas and I use the script editor, but there are things that are complicated and I don't know how to do it through script. Therefore, I have no choice but to resort to formulas. I am not an expert, I have started very recently with google sheets, google apps script and javascript, therefore, my skills do not give much. @Cooper

Comment: Kindly share a dummy spreadsheet with the desired output. Also check [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: The problem was solved with the comment of idfurw @NikkoJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like `IF(C6:C="",,` right after `ARRAYFORMULA`

---

[image]

Comment: I have tried to do what you indicate, but I keep getting the data in the whole column. In short, there has been no change. @idfurw

Comment: It should work. Added a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: You're right!! I have looked at your formula in the image and it turns out that I had put 'IF (C6:C = "" ,,' before 'ARRAYFORMULA ()'. I had understood the order in your comment. This is due to my poor English. I'm sorry! In the end everything is solved, and this solved my problem. Thank you very much!  @idfurw